# hadoop - enum.valueOf - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant

Tags: java, hadoop, enums, illegalargumentexception

I'm having a really strange problem.  I'm sending a string ("ZIP") into my code and I'm trying to convert it to an enum using the valueOf method on the enum.  I'm getting the "No enum constant" illegalArgumentException.

So I added a a two log statements:

```
String optionValue = "[" + cmdLine.getOptionValue("c").replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "") + "]";
StringBuilder types = new StringBuilder();
for (MyType v : MyType.values()) {
    types.append("[" + v.toString() + "] ");           
}
log.info(optionValue+"::"+types);
```

the result of the log is: [ZIP]::[ZIP] [ABC] [DEF]

But I still get the `IllegalArgumentException`.

I'm building the code using maven on my machine and then "putting" it on hdfs using the "put" command so that I can run it.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Have you defined the enums in your class?

Comment: yes I have...otherwise, how would the loop work.

Answer (score 1):

You may have other non-printable chars in your text other that "\n" and "\r". Also, you may need to double-escape.

Try this:

```
optionValue = cmdLine.getOptionValue("c").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
```

Comment: ...or maybe just append `.trim()` method at the end.